# Movie Player requires additional plugins to decode this file

Tags: linux, rhel, free-software, mediaplayer

I'm using **RHEL 6** . I'm unable  to play the video using **Movie Player**. It shows an error, Movie Player requires additional plugins to decode this file. 
The following plugins are required : MPEG-4-AAC decoder and H.264 decoder. But RHEL asking for a subscription. How to solve this problem or Suggest me any alternate softwares to install ?

Comment: Red Hat is a subscription-based, paid enterprise distribution. if you don't like it, get CentOS.

Comment: I'd second strugee's advice, given this issue plus your earlier Q about LibreOffice, you should probably be looking to CentOS instead of RHEL.

Comment: yes, I need CentOS @slm

Comment: Consider using `mplayer`, available at www.mplayerhq.hu.  It comes with most codecs as part of its installation.  There's even pre-built RPMs for RHEL in the "download" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing the [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/) repo and then
`yum install gstreamer-ffmpeg`

Comment: No package gstreamer-ffmpeg available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Did you enable the "nonfree" repository by chance? The package is inside the "free" one. http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/x86_64/repoview/letter_g.group.html

Answer (score 0):

Install oneplay-gstreamer-codecs-pack will solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `gstreamer*` and `vlc`, and ensured that VLC would read the mpeg files

Comment: Hi Leslie Satenstein. How did you do that? What made you choose those particular pieces of software? You should [edit] your answer to provide more details; otherwise, it may be at risk of being deleted as low quality. Answers that give the why and the how are much more useful not only to the person originally asking the question (in this case two and a half years ago) but also to people who might come across this question in the years to come. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in our site's [help] for some further hints.

Answer (score 0):

I got the MPEG-1 video decoder plugin error and it resolved with following:

External repository created through below packages and installed required plugins.

1. epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
2. rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm

Then through Yum installed `gstreamer-ffmpeg.x86_64 0:0.10.11-2.el6` package and its dependency.

```
Installed:
  gstreamer-ffmpeg.x86_64 0:0.10.11-2.el6

Dependency Installed:
  dirac-libs.x86_64 0:1.0.2-4.el6
  ffmpeg-compat.x86_64 0:0.6.7-1.el6
  lame-libs.x86_64 0:3.99.5-1.el6
  librtmp.x86_64 0:2.3-3.el6
  libva.x86_64 0:1.0.15-1.el6
  orc.x86_64 0:0.4.16-6.el6
  schroedinger.x86_64 0:1.0.8-4.el6
  x264-libs.x86_64 0:0.120-5.20120303.el6
  xvidcore.x86_64 0:1.3.2-3.el6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yum install oneplay-gstreamer-codecs-pack
```

did it for me.

Answer (score -1):

The packages that worked for me, using REDHAT 7.4 enterprise, were the following:

```
libavcodec52-32bit-0.7.16-7.1.x86_64.rpm 
gstreamer-ffmpeg-0.10.11-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
*** nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm *** 
epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
```

If you don't find exact, you can always find alternatives, at `http://www.pkgs.org`, just get ur version right i386, i586 or x86_64.

with RH 7.4 u can also use centOS, Fedora & RH & noarch.

Comment: How would you be able to use centOS packages, for example? Can it cause any problems mixing and matching?