# H264 Mpeg-4 missing in fedora 24

Tags: debian, fedora, ffmpeg, codec

I saw an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107493/movie-player-requires-additional-plugins-to-decode-this-file) but when I tried it with `dnf` it says `packages does not exist`. I'm having the sample problem when I try to run videos in my built-in fedora 24 video player (I'm new to linux btw)

Any suggestions to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install the below required packages using yum to resolve your isssue.

Enable the rpmfusion repository.

```
yum localinstall http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-24.noarch.rpm 
yum localinstall http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-24.noarch.rpm

yum -y install gstreamer-plugins-bad gstreamer-plugins-bad-free-extras gstreamer-plugins-bad-nonfree gstreamer-plugins-ugly gstreamer-ffmpeg

yum -y install gstreamer1-libav gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-extras gstreamer1-plugins-bad-freeworld gstreamer1-plugins-base-tools gstreamer1-plugins-good-extras gstreamer1-plugins-ugly gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free gstreamer1-plugins-good gstreamer1-plugins-base gstreamer1
```

ffmpeg

```
yum -y install ffmpeg
```

Mencoder

```
yum -y install mencoder
```

ffmpeg2 theora

```
yum -y install ffmpeg2theora
```

Mplayer

```
yum -y install mplayer
```

Play dvd

```
yum -y install libdvdread libdvdnav lsdvd libdvdcss
```

Comment: Thank You sir. It worked perfectly. Actually what I did is ONLY running the 4 `Enable the rpmfusion repository`  commands you provided. I had already installed `ffmpeg` before. So the remaining 4 commands of your post have not been runned. And it works. **Conclusion** : `Enable the rpmfusion repository`  commands and `ffmpeg` installation did the job for me. Thank you